# Accessing servlets in Websphere

Tags: java, servlets, websphere

I have written a simple test servlet and deployed it on websphere applications.

When i try to access the servlet it gives me following error

> Error 404: SRVE0190E:

I have checked all the basic things like web.xml entry, servlet syntax etc.

Everything is correct.. The same servlet when deployed on Tomcat is working fine.

I also checked the

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility property in Servers > Server > Web Container Settings > Web Container > Custom Properties .. it is set to true.

Not getting exactly what is the issue. If any one could help to resolve this issue

The serlvet that i created :

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public TestServlet() {      
        super();
     }
    
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
     throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();     
        out.print("This is a testing servlet ... Please ignore");
    }
    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
     throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request,response);            
    }
}
```

Entry in web.xml :

```
 <servlet>
      <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>              
      <servlet-class>com.wizard.servlet.TestServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

The war file which contains the servlet is deployed on one of the cells in Websphere server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding the source code for the servlet to your question.

Comment: A HTTP 404 error is related to Directory or File Not Found. I agree, you will have to provide some source.

Comment: @P.E : Whats the full URL you are using to access?

Comment: I m accessing the servlet /LotusWizard/TestServlet

The former one is the context-root

Comment: @P.E : does /LotusWizard/ alone give anything?

Comment: no if you call any jsp or any struts action along with the context it is coming properly .. I mean it is giving the desired result. Only when a servlet is called it is throwing 404

Comment: Read the server startup logs for any errors/warnings.

Comment: The server startup logs does not contain any errors...

Comment: Are you using struts 1? If actions are working as you say, then the struts front controller servlet works at least.

Comment: yes i m using struts 1.. and thts wat is really disturbing.. Action servlets are working fine, but a generic servlet is not

Comment: Can any one please help to solve this problem. I simple can't understand why a simple servlet is not accessible. All the necessary coding has been written. Infact the same code without any change works on Tomcat .

Comment: Is that the full error? If not, can you paste the whole thing? What port are you hitting, and is that the port in the Web Container or for an HTTP server in front of WAS?